# How to integrate cpprestsdk with Apache web server?

Tags: apache, cpprest-sdk

Is there a way to integrate cpprestsdk (https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) with Apache web server?

We have our web server configured with Apache 2.2 with C++ modules. Now, I want to provide REST API and want to utilize existing Apache Web server.

Looking at options, I found that C++ REST SDK has C++ framework for REST API. I want to understand, is there any way that I can integrate C++ REST SDK with Apache and use Apache as web server to provide Rest API?

Comment: Hi @shrek and welcome to StackOverflow. I don't know much about apache or cpprest-sdk but as a reviewer on SO I would encourage you to try and formulate your question a bit more specific than this. We tend to favor code-specific questions on SO and at the moment your question is still broad. If you're in doubt I recommend reading through ˋ[ask]ˋ as well :-)